# How to make and check a user and password on android application?

Tags: android, networking

I have a database server which collect user&pass of users (by login from website). On android application, I want to check user&pass, but I don't know how I send and receive data.

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query your database, go ahead. Java SE and Android have something called javax.sql that allows you to interact with relational databases. You need a pure Java JDBC driver for the specific database you are querying against.

You have a good chance of being able to import the pure Java (SE) driver into android and having it work, but it's not guaranteed. if the driver uses some library that's available on java SE and not android, you are out of luck (but i don't know what that'd be).

That being said, you might be better off building a web service front end to your database to allow the client to make simplified, specific queries instead of exposing the entire database to the client. This is for security reasons, and also because in general it's better to push off as much work to the server as possible when writing for mobile clients.